# OpenLayers Map deployment

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, deployment, openlayers

I am relatively new using aspnet core and openlayers.
I have my map running using npm. Basic map with 5 layers. All looks great using the local host with NPM. I used 'npm run build' and I see the build directory with my data, index and js files.  When I open the index.html in chrome it does NOT show the layers.  When I update the remote hosted web site it also does not show the layers.  (Basic map does show).
Looking at the index page, it has the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

My JS file is located in wwwroot\js\main.js so I changed that line to: (hope that this was the right thing to do):

```
<script src="~/js/main.js"></script>
```

The Data files are located in wwwroot/data/brandywine3.gpx.
The code referal (1 of 5) is as follows:

```
url: './data/brandywine1.gpx',
```

Missing something.  Any suggestions as to what I need to do to get the layers to display?

Please remeber, that I am new at this.  So detail responses will be appreciated.
I have never been able to get the layer data to display.  So now hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

The full Main.JS file is as follows:

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
//import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';
//import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer.js';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import View from 'ol/View';
import {fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj';
import GPX from 'ol/format/GPX.js';
import {Circle as CircleStyle, Fill, Stroke, Style} from 'ol/style.js';
//import Overlay from 'ol/Overlay';


 var style = {
        'Point': new Style({
          image: new CircleStyle({
            fill: new Fill({
              color: 'red'
            }),
            radius: 3,
            stroke: new Stroke({
              color: '#ff0',
              width: 1
            })
          })
        }),
        'LineString': new Style({
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: '#f00',
            width: 10
          })
        }),
        'MultiLineString': new Style({
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: '#0f0',
            width: 5
          })
        })
        ,
        'MultiLineString2': new Style({
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: 'red',
            width: 5
          })
        }),
        'MultiLineString3': new Style({
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 5
          })
        }),
        'MultiLineStringMetalDome': new Style({
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: 'orange',
            width: 5
          })
        }),
        'MultiLineStringBCS': new Style({
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: 'red',
            width: 5
          })
        })
      };

var mapSelect = document.getElementById('Map-select');
var DisplayBCSTrails = document.getElementById('DisplayBCSTrails');
var DisplayWPTs = document.getElementById('DisplayWPTs');
var DisplayMetalDomeTrail = document.getElementById('DisplayMetalDomeTrail');


var tileLayer = new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM()
      });

var vector = new VectorLayer({
        source: new VectorSource({
          url: './data/brandywine1.gpx',
          format: new GPX()
        }),
         style: function(feature) {
           return style[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
         },
        visible: true        
    });


var vector2 = new VectorLayer({
        source: new VectorSource({
          url: './data/brandywine2.gpx',
          format: new GPX()
        }),
        // style: new Style({
            // color: 'red',
            // width: 5
        // })
        style: function(feature) {
           return style['MultiLineString2'];
         },
        visible: true
      });  
var vector3 = new VectorLayer({
        source: new VectorSource({
          url: './data/brandywine3.gpx',
          format: new GPX()
        }),
        // style: new Style({
            // color: 'red',
            // width: 5
        // })
        style: function(feature) {
           return style['MultiLineString3'];
         },
        visible: true
      });     

var vectorMetalDome = new VectorLayer({
        source: new VectorSource({
          url: './data/MetalDome.gpx',
          format: new GPX()
        }),
        style: function(feature) {
           return style['MultiLineStringMetalDome'];
         },
        visible: true
      });  

var vectorBCS = new VectorLayer({
        source: new VectorSource({
          url: './data/BCSTrails.gpx',
          format: new GPX()
        }),
        style: function(feature) {
           return style['MultiLineStringBCS'];
         },
        visible: true
      });  

var vectorWPTs = new VectorLayer({
        source: new VectorSource({
          url: './data/BrandywineWPTs.gpx',
          format: new GPX()
        }),
        style: function(feature) {
           return style['Point'];
         },
        visible: true
      });         

var map = new Map({
      target: 'map-container',
      layers: [tileLayer, vector, vector2, vector3, vectorMetalDome, vectorBCS, vectorWPTs],
      view: new View({
            center: fromLonLat([-123.191558, 50.090620]),
        zoom: 12
        })
    });

function ToggleBCSTrailsDisplay() {
    if(vectorBCS.visible === false){
        vectorBCS.visible = true;
        vectorBCS.setVisible(true);
        }
    else{
        vectorBCS.visible = false;
        vectorBCS.setVisible(false);
        }
}
function ToggleWPTDisplay() {
    if (vectorWPTs.visible === false) {
        vectorWPTs.visible = true;
        vectorWPTs.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        vectorWPTs.visible = false;
        vectorWPTs.setVisible(false);
    }
}
function ToggleDisplayMetalDomeTrail() {
    if(vectorMetalDome.visible === false) {
        vectorMetalDome.visible = true;
        vectorMetalDome.setVisible(true);}
    else {
            vectorMetalDome.visible = false;
            vectorMetalDome.setVisible(false);
        }
}

DisplayBCSTrails.addEventListener('click', ToggleBCSTrailsDisplay);
DisplayWPTs.addEventListener('click', ToggleWPTDisplay);
DisplayMetalDomeTrail.addEventListener('click', ToggleDisplayMetalDomeTrail);
```